# Cannot assign type 'number[]' to type '[[number]]'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

### i have 2 models in mongoose , i want to assign values in the second model to the first one .

the geometry representation in first model 1st
`

```
geometry: {
        type: string;
        coordinates?: [[number]];
    };
```

### `

the geometry representation in second model 2nd

```
geometry: {
        type: string;
        coordinates?: [type: [number]];
    };
```

---

### here is the representation of my assignement as u can see we have the first model representated in left side as a started line , the second model is which one i grab data and i'm using map méthod to loop inside it.

```
geometry: {
                    type: client.geometry.type, 
                    coordinates: client.geometry.coordinates?.flatMap((coordinates) => coordinates)
                }
```

[the error i received is captured in a clear image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtwHf.png)

how i can solve this problem?

-- keyword:

**number[]**     **[[number]]**

i've tried to cast value . no effect same problem

Comment: So from my understanding, the first model is a double array of number, and second model is a normal array number correct? If so why can't you just map `[number]` instead of `[type: [number]]` on the second model?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign `number[]` to `number[][]` (more wide type of `[[number]]`)

Thast is caused by `Array<T[]>.flatMap()` returning `T[]` instead of `T[][]` as you expect, because `flatMap` always flattens out one level of array

You probably need to use `.map(e => e)` instead, or `.flatMap(e => e).map(e => [e])`

Comment: thank you for your good response. it make sens clearly.
Impossible d'assigner le type 'number[]' au type '[number]' , i keep having the same error